# Wrong answer from a program (infix notation->postfix notation) in C

Tags: c, stack

I made a program which changes infix notation to postfix notation with using stack in C.

I made a function which prints the result of the postfix notation(from infix notaton).

But, the result of a notation is wrong. This should be '195' but its result is '-61'.

The results of the other notations are right but only the notation(op2) has this problem.

What should I do to fix this problem?

**This is my code:**

```
typedef char element;
 
typedef struct {
    element stack[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    int top;
} StackType;
 

void init(StackType *s) {
    s->top = -1;
}

int is_empty(StackType *s) {
    return (s->top == -1);
}

int is_full(StackType *s) {
    return (s->top == (MAX_STACK_SIZE - 1));
}

 
void push(StackType *s, element item) {
    if (is_full(s)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "FULL STACK ERROR\n");
        return;
    }
    else s->stack[++(s->top)] = item;
}
 
element pop(StackType *s) {
    if (is_empty(s)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "EMPTY STACK ERROR\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else return s->stack[(s->top)--];
}
 
 
int eval(char exp[]) {
    int op1, op2, value, i = 0;
    int len = strlen(exp);
    char ch;
    StackType s;
    init(&s);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        ch = exp[i];
        if (ch != '+' && ch != '-' && ch != '*' && ch != '/') {
            value = ch - '0';        
            push(&s, value);
        }
        else {                          
            op2 = pop(&s);
            op1 = pop(&s);
            switch (ch) {            
            case '+': push(&s, op1 + op2); break;
            case '-': push(&s, op1 - op2); break;
            case '*': push(&s, op1 * op2); break;
            case '/': push(&s, op1 / op2); break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pop(&s);
}
 
char* infix_to_postfix(char exp[]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char ch, top_op;
    int len = strlen(exp);
    char *ex = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len + 1));
    StackType s;

    init(&s);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        ch = exp[i];
        switch (ch) {
        case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/': 
            while (!is_empty(&s) && (prec(ch) <= prec(peek(&s)))) {
                ex[j++] = pop(&s);
            }
            push(&s, ch);
            break;
        case '(':       
            push(&s, ch);
            break;
        case ')':       
            top_op = pop(&s);
            while (top_op != '(') {
                ex[j++] = top_op;
                top_op = pop(&s);
            }
            break;
        default:
            ex[j++] = ch;
            break;
        }
    }
    while (!is_empty(&s)) {
        ex[j++] = pop(&s);
    }
    ex[j] = NULL;           
    return ex;
}

void main() {
    char *op1 = "(9-(3+2))*3+4*((4+2)/3)-1";
    char *op2 = "(4*5-3)/3+((2+5*7)-8+9)*5";          
    char *op3 = "7*3-7-4+1/3+6-8*2";
    char *pos1, *pos2, *pos3;
 
    pos1 = infix_to_postfix(op1);
    pos2 = infix_to_postfix(op2);
    pos3 = infix_to_postfix(op3);
 
    printf(" Result : %d\n", eval(pos1));
    printf(" Result : %d\n", eval(pos2));
    printf(" Result : %d\n", eval(pos3));
}
```

**[RESULT]**

> Result : 19
>
> Result : -61   // This should be '195'.
>
> Result : 0

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but even though strings are null-terminated it doesn't mean `NULL`. `NULL` is used for null *pointers*. The null-termination character is either `'\0'` or its integer equivalent `0`.

Comment: As for your problem, please take some time to read about [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. Also I recommend you to print out e.g. `pos2` to make sure the postfix expression is correct.

Comment: Hmm... interesting that `-61 + 256 == 195`. Signed overflow?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for your advice! The code was from a tutorial book for Data Structure in C. And I added some parts to make a prgoram which has the function by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue is `61+195 = 256`. Which means that somewhere, your computations are being saved to chars.  Looks like it is `element`.

```
typedef element int;
```

Comment: Thak you! I changed 'char' into 'int' and it works well. I was forgetting that I didn't change the part to make the program...